# Where to put Dependency Injection classes in clean architecture

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, clean-architecture

In clean architecture, if I'm organizing my packages by feature. where to put dependency injection `Dagger2` class code ?

Comment: You can follow this Example https://github.com/burhanrashid52/AndroidDaggerMVPRxArchitecture

Comment: Classes should be designed around *Constructor Injection* and classes should be composed (or registered) in the *[Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the good comments you received above, you should group your classes by feature in packages and put the Dagger 2 `Component` and `Module` classes in that package.

Refer to the Google Android Architecture Blueprints [Dagger/MVP sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/).

There is a root package for the Application class and the app-scoped module and component. From that root package, there are the following sub-packages grouped by feature:

```
addedittask 
statistics
taskdetail  
tasks
util
```

Inside the package there are the following classes:

```
TaskDetailActivity.java
TaskDetailComponent.java
TaskDetailContract.java
TaskDetailFragment.java 
TaskDetailPresenter.java
TaskDetailPresenterModule.java
```

The benefit of doing this is you can use [access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to prevent unintended usages of your classes. This fulfils Effective Java Item 13 - *Minimize the accesibility of classes and members*.